# Remove bracket in a list of tuples in tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I would like to remove the bracket of a tuples who belong to tuples within a list:

Here's an example:

```
List_1 = [(0, (1, 1)),
 (0, (1, 2)),
 (0, (1, 3))]
```

And the expected output should look like this:

```
list_2 = [(0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3)]
```

I tried this:

```
for element in List_n_d1d2:
    newlist = (element[0], element[1])
```

But ended up with the same output... Could you please help me, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `*` spread operator to expand the tuple into separate elements.

```
list_2 = [(a, *b) for a, b in list_1]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple comprehension would be:

```
[(a,) + b for a,b in List_1]
```